# java: using regex to parse repeated substrings

Tags: java, regex

This is specifically aimed at parsing hex bytes, but there's a more general question here.

Suppose I have a regexp `r` e.g. `\\s*([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})\\s*` (optional spaces, 2 hex digits that I'm interested in, and optional spaces).

If I want to parse a string `s` with this regexp such that:

- if `s` can be divided into a sequence of blocks that matches `r`, I want to do something for each block. (e.g. `ff 7c 0903   02BB aC` could be divided in this way.)
- If `s` cannot be divided accordingly, I want to detect this. (e.g. `00 01 02 hi there ab ff` and `9 0 2 1 0` and `Y0 DEADBEEF` and `cafe BABE!` all fail.)

how could I do this with Java's regexp facilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to use the regex matcher stuff and the lookingAt() method.

Something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "\\s*([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( myString );
int lastEnd = 0;
while( m.lookingAt() ) {
    System.out.println( "Hex part:" + m.group(1) );
    lastEnd = m.end();
}   
if( lastEnd < myString.length() ) {
    System.err.println( "Encountered non-hex value at index:" + lastEnd );
}
```

...or whatever.  lookingAt() has to start at the current position and so the matches must all be contiguous.  The only error condition to catch is finishing early since that means non-hex-formatted data was encountered.

Comment: neat! I ended up doing this approach manually (checking the previous end() vs. the current start()), didn't know about lookingAt().

Comment: That's not right. `lookingAt()` only matches at the beginning of the Matcher's region, which is the beginning of the string by default. You *could* make this approach work by constantly changing the starting bound of the region, but it's much easier just to prepend `\G` to the regex and use `find()`. As it is, your code just keeps matching the first two hex digits in an infinite loop (if it matches anything, that is).

Comment: He's right.  The code I've done that used lookingAt() for similar purpose was also chopping the string up each time... which is another option.  myString = myString.substring(lastEnd) is nearly free.  I forgot to put it.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a use case for [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). You could use either [`next(String)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String)) or [`next(Pattern)`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.util.regex.Pattern)) to discover whether the next token matched your regex.

I don't have a compiler handy, but I think it would go something like this:

```
Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(mySource);
// default delimiter is any whitespace, so you don't need to call useDelimiter()
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})\\s*");
String s = null;
while ((s = myScanner.next(myPattern)) != null) {
    // do something with the token
}
```

Comment: interesting, ok, how can I make sure there's no non-matching input before/after/between tokens?

Comment: Hmm... it's been a while, but I think you'd have to try `hasNext()` and `skip()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the complete input by adding anchors, or by using `matches()` instead of `contains()`, the regexp becomes:

```
^(\\s*([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}))+\\s*$
```

If this rgeexp matches, you can then proceed and iterate over the matches for:

```
\\s*([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})
```

to pick up the hex bytes.

Comment: wasn't planning on using 2 regexps, but this is certainly simple + straightforward.

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but the other method you're thinking of is `Matcher#find()`; `contains()` is a String method that just does a literal text search.

Comment: @Alan, thanks for your remark, I was refering to the Jakarta ORO methods matches and contains.